# Как передать данные в html из node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, json, http

Мне нужно, чтоб индексация страницы происходила как с шаблонизатором ejs, т.е. только стандартный server http на node.js modul fs.
Если добавлять

```js
document.querSelector( 'head > meta[name="description"]' ).innerHTML = `description`;
```

то тогда сайт появляется в поисковой выдачи Google с тем-же заголовком и описанием, которые были в первые секунды отрисовки. В Яндексе будет тоже самое, тем более Яндекс медленнее сканирует страницы, но факт, что в поисковой выдаче страница с неизмененным заголовком и описанием отображается, а это нужно изменить.

Как можно передать в index.html?eng данные на страницу, чтоб была отрисовка в поисковиках, сразу же, без использования ejs с одними только стандартными функциями http and fs, т.е. в стандартном node.js пакете без установленных пакетов?

Пытался так:

```js
if( request.url === "/json" ) {
  const data = {};
  data.description = "oK oK oK description";
  data.title = "title";
  request.on( "end", () => {
    response.end( data );
  });
}
```

Потом писал в meta="descritption" content=`${data.description}` - но данные так и не передаются. Есть же какой-нибудь способ сразу отобразить подобным образом данные, чтобы они появились при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Вы либо дробите 1 html на множество под ваши страницы, с нужными заголовками и текстом, либо ставите себе шаблонизатор на node.js. по другому не получится.

Comment: Скорее всего, то что берут роботы это страница без запуска JS поэтому в return c cервера нужно вернуть готовую, ejs не обязателен, можно свой велосипед сделать.

Comment: Ок, можно по подробнее о "велосепеде" - все догадки будут плюсом! Заранее спасибо! Сейчас видно что гугл в поисковой выдачи отображает дескрипшин на русском со страницей где язык меняется на енглиш и дескрипшин изменяется яваскриптом только когда есть переход на сайт. Как то надо изменить видимость из поиска до перехода. Тоесть чтобы видимость была что страница с ссылкой ?линк изменилась и в поисковой выдачи. Когда она по факту менятся только при переходе на неё когда выполняется яваскрипт.

Comment: Вам нужно возвращать не `JSON` а страницу (уже готовую) как это делается фреймворках с  `SSR` ( рендерингом страницы на стороне сервера) тогда у поисковиков не будет других вариантов. Поисковые выдачи насколько я знаю обновляются не мгновенно (могу ошибаться)